# How do I install the latest OpenOffice.org?

Tags: software-installation, openoffice.org

Today I downloaded and installed OpenOffice through the PPA repositories, using apt-get (hope that's what I mean to say), and when the program checked for updates it said there was a new version - 3.4.1 which I need to download from the website.

I am reluctant to download from the website, because I tried this earlier (before using the PPAs) and while I was able to download the .tar.gz file and extract the DEBS, I couldn't figure out how to install it.  I found instructions on the internet that told me how to install, but for some reason, Ubuntu didn't know the application was installed!  Couldn't find it in Dash, and to run I had to find the OpenOffice folder and doubleclick soffice.bin.

So my question is, how to I download and install the latest version of OpenOffice without it being messed up as above?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu comes with an office suit by default, called Libre Office. If you would still like to install Open Office follow these directions.

### Download..

Download Open Office from [Openoffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org/) (or use this [direct link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/latest/download?source=dlp)).
Save the file to your Downloads folder.

### Install..

**I highly recommend that you remove ALL previously installed versions of Open Office before proceeding!**

Open a terminal and `cd` to the downloads folder:

```
cd Downloads
```

Now we need to untar the installation folder:

```
tar -xvzf Apache_OpenOffice_incubating_3.4.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
```

Then `cd` to the folder we just extracted:

```
cd en-GB/DEBS
```

And install all the packages:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

When that has finished `cd` to the "Desktop Integration" folder:

```
cd desktop-integration
```

and install those packages:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

And you're done!

You can now remove the `en-GB` folder.

Comment: I just would like to make it clear for the author of question: it is important to install _all_ packages at once, that's why `dpkg -i *.deb` can't be replaced with multiple `dpkg -i %package%` commands unless you guess the correct order of installation to resolve all dependencies. That's the only problem that makes it a bad idea to use graphical package installers for these DEB packages.

Comment: Seth - I did what you suggested the first time I tried to install OpenOffice, but it didn't work because Ubuntu didn't know Open Office was installed.  I couldn't find it in Dash, and couldn't associate it with file types, and the only way I could run it was by going into the /opt/openoffice.org3/program folder and running soffice.bin.

If the method you suggest is the only way to do it then I'll have to just stick with the older version unfortunately.

Comment: @SamH Did you install the desktop integration packages?  Those are what put the icons in the dash.

Comment: @Seth, yes I did.  Did it straight after I installed everything else.  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Ok, it's working!

I used apt-get --purge OpenOfficeorg to remove the software, then I downloaded the package and used the dpkg -i command to install all the debs. Then I installed the desktop-integration debs, and it is all working now!

In short I have no idea what I did wrong last time, but it is working! Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: @SamH You might have had to reboot. So far I'm not getting any icons either, but I haven't rebooted yet.