# How to install openoffice? yes, I am total noob

Tags: dpkg, deb, openoffice.org

I've downloaded the .deb version from the website. A tar.gz file. Then I extracted it. It gives me 3 folders: DEBS, Licences, readme.

[image: terminal]

There are loads of .deb files. So am I installing the one with the largest size called core04, because I did do this:

> dpkg -i openoffice-core04_4.1.2-3_amd64.deb

it is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install OpenOffice.org instead of LibreOffice?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/116590/how-do-i-install-openoffice-org-instead-of-libreoffice) or [How do I install the latest OpenOffice.org?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/294903/how-do-i-install-the-latest-openoffice-org)

Comment: I recommend using LibreOffice instead though, it's almost the same and comes preinstalled by default.

Comment: When you tried to install, you were in the wrong directory, you must be in /DEBS to install them, you seem to of changed to that folder after running dpkg, so `cd/DEBS && sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Answer (score 0):

Go to DEBS folder and execute `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

This installs Openoffice in /opt by default.

To install the Desktop integreations go into the dekstop-integration folder and execute the same command as above.

For further details please see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116590/how-do-i-install-openoffice-org-instead-of-libreoffice).

Comment: Are you sure it installs OpenOffice in /opt? Sounds like a throwing stone in the dark

Comment: I did all that and I am sure it installed but there is no openoffice when I search in the bar!? I restarted but nothing http://s16.postimg.org/6cgm1458l/Screenshot_from_2016_09_27_20_59_43.png?2

Comment: Did you remove Libreoffce? It could clash with OpenOffice.

Can you execute `soffice` and `libreoffice` commands seperately?  What do they do?

Can you go into the /usr/bin folder and execute `file soffice` comman? It may say *symbolic link to ../lib/libreoffice/program/soffice*.

Comment: Yes, I removed libreoffice already. When I go to /usr/bin folder no such file as soffice!? But I see openoffice in "apt list --installed". I am going to uninstall everything and reinstall and see I can solve the problem

Comment: Finally got it working. Looks like I had to reinstall everything. Thank you for your help Mustafa.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want you can install all of them, but what's really important is that you install the **core** of the program. The core is basically the hub of the whole program (you will just see in dash as 'OpenOffice #' with # being the version number). It will install the rest of the program along with the libraries into the place you desire. As @Mustafa said,

> This installs Openoffice in /opt by default.

So you probably won't have to change the installation path.

But if you *do* want to install desktop integrations (e.g. shorcuts and app links) Then you may wanna put it into the desktop-integrations folder.

Answer (score 0):

Well first thing to do is remove Libreoffice if its installed. Just
 press Ctrl+Alt+T on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run
 the command(s) below:

> ```
> sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
> sudo apt-get clean
> sudo apt-get autoremove
> Then to install OpenOffice you do:
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/openoffice 
> sudo apt-get update 
> sudo apt-get install apache-openoffice
> ```
>
> I just tested it on 13.04, and it works.

Source for OpenOffice Install:[Upubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/59676/mitch)

Originally posted by [Mitch](https://askubuntu.com/users/59676/mitch)

Comment: This isn't working. I got "E: Unable to locate package apache-openoffice" I am running 16.04